# Eclipse - Cucumber plugin - Preferences - Cucumber > Java page does not load

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, cucumber

The cucumber plugin was installed in eclipse by accessing following url:
Cucumber-Eclipse - https://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-eclipse/update-site/main/

After this, when trying to access the Preferences > Cucumber > Java page in Eclipse, an error pop up is displayed:
[image: Cucumber > Java Preferences page]

I was having Java 8 installed in the machine. I tried installing a higher Java version (Java 11) as I understand that there are issues with older Java versions with eclipse versions.
After that I changed the Installed JREs selection to JDK 11.
Still same issue was happening.

Adding the error under Details:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW4eF.png)

Comment: It looks like the cucumber plug-in is out of date. The `FilterViewerComparator` class it is looking for has been moved in recent releases of Eclipse so it won't work.

Comment: What is reported there if you expand `[Details >>>]` ?

Comment: @AlexeyR. Added the error screenshot in the description above.

Comment: @greg-449, In that case, which url should I use to search and install the cucumber plugin that is up to date? And that will not give this issue in eclipse ?

Comment: As far as I can see the plug-in has not been updated for some time so there is no fix. You would have to contact the developers.