# Facing issue on loading the cucumber plugin via Install New Software > Add > Archive with cucumber jar file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, eclipse-plugin, cucumber, eclipse-marketplace

After loading the cucumber jar zip file and clicking on "Next" button, thhe loading will be stuck at this step for long time: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Td09t.png)

Then it will error out with this message:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2irm.png)
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Cucumber Eclipse 1.0.0.202107150747 (cucumber.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.202107150747)
Missing requirement: Cucumber Editor 1.0.0.202107150747 (cucumber.eclipse.editor 1.0.0.202107150747) requires 'osgi.bundle; org.eclipse.pde.ui 3.5.0' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: Cucumber Eclipse 1.0.0.202107150747 (cucumber.eclipse.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.202107150747)
To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; cucumber.eclipse.editor [1.0.0.202107150747,1.0.0.202107150747]

Using this version of Eclipse: 2022-03 version

Tried many work arounds mentioned around this cucumber install issue but none worked.
Note: Cannot access the eclipse marketplace to install the plugin.

Comment: As reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75955806/2670892) there does not appear to be a version of this plug-in which works with the current Eclipse.